# How to create a search system like Unsplash?

Tags: php, json, reactjs

When I create a search bar I always use the GET method. If a person searches for the word "code" the link will be: www.mywebsite.com/search?q=code
But at Unsplash, when you search the word code the link will be:
https://unsplash.com/search/photos/code

I copied this link, and I wrote all the words, even my first name (https://unsplash.com/search/photos/zayad) and I found a page with the images related to the searched words.

Do you have an idea on how, can I do the same thing in my website?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript. They intercept the form submission, update the address bar and redraw the page using JavaScript.

On the results page, they parse the URI in the address bar, make an AJAX request based on the search term they extract, and then update the page with the returned results.

Answer (score 0):

Unsplash uses angularjs, that allows you to pass text from your  text box as parameters quite easily. Wappalyzer says that Unsplash uses angularjs. Check out angularjs